# Javascript field.setCustomValidity() doesn't set field to valid

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form and using Javascript to validate the form. However, when I use setCustomValidity(), it doesn't seem to work properly. I have to click on the submit button twice to mark the field as invalid, and then when the correct input is entered, the field is not marked as valid again, i.e. the error message keeps repeating.
Here's my HTML:

```
<form id="data_form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return validateForm();">
   <table>
       <tr> 
          <td colspan="2" class="right_align"> 
              <label for="supplier_ref"> Supplier Reference Number: </label>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2">
              <input id="supplier_ref" name="supplier_ref" type="number" required>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <!-- more rows -->
       <button id="generate" name="generate" type="submit" onclick=""> Generate Barcode </button>
   </table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function validateForm() {
    var form = document.forms["data_form"];
    var emptymsg = "Field must be filled out.";
    var supplier_ref = form.elements["supplier_ref"];
    var supplier_ref_value = supplier_ref.value.toString();
    if (supplier_ref_value == "") {
      supplier_ref.setCustomValidity(emptymsg);
      return false;
    }
    if (supplier_ref_value.length != 9){
      supplier_ref.setCustomValidity("Number has to be 9 digits long.");
      return false;
    } else {
      supplier_ref.setCustomValidity("");
    }
    return true;
}
```

When the length of the Supplier Reference is less than 9 digits, the error message appears, but when I enter the correct length, I still get the same error.
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nvm it only works with addEventListener